# Is it possible to use the CachingSagaStore while using multiple segments?

Tags: axon

I believe we could benefit from caching our `SagaStore`.
So, to configure the `CachingSagaStore`.
The cache is written through, which covers moving from node-1 to node-2.

What happens though when the `StreamingEventProcessor` moves back to node-1 and the state was changed on node-2?

All associations are set at saga's start.

Application context:

- Axon Framework version 4
- Two application nodes
- Four segments for our sagas

Answer (score 0):

Found it, reading the javadoc will help..

"The tracking token of the event last handled by the Saga is also passed as a parameter."

...

Hmm that does not solve it.. a) the token is not passed, b) it would not solve the issue :- )

caching is hard!

Comment: It is not a 100% clear whether you feel your answer solves the problem at hand Jan. Would you mind elaborating whether you are still looking for a more thorough solution to this problem?

Comment: i'd already moved on, but true, I'm not answered yet actually. I'll try to update question or maybe use the community site.